# Dialogs not visible in ExcelApplication embedded into a UserControl into a wpf window

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, xaml

Coding in C# and xaml code.
I need to load in a modeless wpf window an Excel application using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.
I made a UserControl which creates a new Excel.Application and setting the excelHandle application to my UserControl:

```
application = new Excel.Application();
excelHandle = new IntPtr(application.Hwnd); 
SetParent(excelHandle, this.Handle);
```

After, in my Wpf Window, in xaml code I've got this:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="1">
<excel:ExcelView x:Name="excel" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

My code is based on this code: https://www.cnblogs.com/redalert2c/articles/2760352.html

My problem is: when Excel calls a dialog window like File->Open or Change the paragraph format, all the dialogs are not in the good parent and hidden I don't know where...

How to make sure the Excel dialogs get the current Parent?

Thanks